# I'm trying to query in Opensearch with python, and having trouble getting a response

Tags: python, elasticsearch, robotframework, opensearch

```
def create_open_search_session(host, port):
    auth = ('pass', 'pass')
    client = OpenSearch(
        hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': port}],
        httP_compress = True,
        http_auth=auth,
        use_ssl=False,
        ssl_assert_hostname=False,
        ssl_show_warn=False,
        verify_certs=True,
        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    )
    return client

def get_severity(host, port):
    try:
        query = {"query":
                     {"match":
                          {"car_make": "toyota"
                           }
                      }
                 }
        os = create_open_search_session(host, port)
        data = wr.opensearch.search(client=os, index="cars", search_body=query)
        # data.head()
        output = json.loads(data)
        return output
    except SSLError as e:
        print("SSL error : ", e)
```

Here is the error im getting
[ WARN ] POST http://192.168.14.180:5601/cars_toyota_search?filter_path=hits.hits._id%2Chits.hits._source [status:404 request:0.043s]

Comment: The 404 suggests you're accessing a URL that doesn't exist. (I attempted to correct the dog's breakfast you've made of indentation and code highlighting, but you rejected that edit - as presented, the code would not compile, let alone run). From the IP, it would appear you're either accessing a service running on a local network, or trying to access a service through some sort of proxy - probably where you should start looking.

Comment: I was able to get 200 response without the query, but when trying to query in opensearch im getting errors, I'm sorry im new to this.

Comment: Is your ES listening on 5601 or have you forwarded that address to the opensearch cluster ?

Comment: 5601 is forwarded to opensearch cluster